# Memcached install error

Tags: memcached

I want to install Memcached on a Windows 7 32-bit computer, but it gives this error:

```
C:\Memcached>memcached.exe -d install
failed to install service or service already installed
```

Comment: No worries, I will post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

> If you are using Windows Vista and Windows 7 system please be execute
>   the command through the administrator role. Right-click the command
>   item in the start menu and use “Run as Administrator”, otherwise the
>   Memcached would not be able to be installed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 7 system make sure you execute the command through the administrator role. Right-click the command item in the start menu and use “Run as Administrator”, otherwise the Memcached would not be able to be installed successfully.